# vba data type question - how to insert a number correctly (with comma)?

Tags: excel, vba

I get type mismatch error when I run the function. Values are like 4476,7873900342471 (Foreign currency) rounded to two decimal places so I have in the worksheet like 4476,79. What type should val have?

```
Function findValues()

Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long 
Dim val As Double

Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1")

LastRow = Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To LastRow

val = Sheet.Range("O" & i).Value

    Sheet.Range("T" & i).Value = val

Next i
End Function
```

Comment: What are you doing with this number exactly? You could just do `Sheet.Range("T2:T" & LastRow).Value = Sheet.Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Value`.

Comment: I transfer value from O to another function (Run addValues(val). For my question this (Sheet.Range("T" & i).Value = val) isin't metter, the error still show up. The error is in val type

Comment: `Dim val As Variant`  But you may want to look at the value in that cell and make sure it is a double and not text that looks like a number.

Comment: Try cast the value to double before assigning it into the val variable: `val = CDbl(Sheet.Range("O" & i).Value)`

Comment: You can check the type that vba thinks the `.Value` is with typename(Sheet.Range("O" & i).Value) - this as a way of helping you debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

My last row included empty rows in which there were functions - that caused mismatch. I applied `LastRow = Columns("O").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).row`, now it correctly counts the number of rows and it worked. Thanks all